# Compare xmls using dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 different xmls , I need to create a 2 different dictionary for these xmls and then need to compare.
Both xmls have different tag and parent / child nodes are different.Please suggest.

XML1:

```
            <REMEMBER xmlns:ns0="http://testsite.com/man/schma/vfg">   <ICDVersion>11.0</ICDVersion>
               <T_MSGH>
                  <Source xmlns:ns4="http://testsite.com/man/schma/vfg/core">PDD</Source>
                  <NAME xmlns:ns5="http://testsite.com/man/schma/vfg/core">ALPHA</NAME>
               </T_MSGH>
               <T_PAR>YAMAHA</T_PAR>
               <T_CUS>FRENVH1234</T_CUS>
               <T_ORP>
                  <FirstName xmlns:ns6="http://testsite.com/man/schma/vfg/core">MEENA</FirstName>
                  <LastName xmlns:ns7="http://testsite.com/man/schma/vfg/core">SINGH</LastName>
               </T_ORP>
               <T_RAMBO>
                  <Street1 xmlns:ns9="http://testsite.com/man/schma/vfg/core">2123 REMAN</Street1>
                  <City xmlns:ns10="http://testsite.com/man/schma/vfg/core">FRANC</City>
               </T_RAMBO>
               <T_EMAIL>NANCY@NANCY.COM</T_EMAIL>
            </REMEMBER>
```

XML2:

```
            <?xml version="1.0"?><ALPHA_Output xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://DECEEMBER.ABC.COM/xml/INFO_OUTPUT.xsd">
            <PO>
             <PO_ID>3557698</PO_ID>
             <MAN>HQF011512C</MAN>
             <SUCCESS>SUCCESS</SUCCESS>
              <DSO_INFO>
               <A key='POC2_FULL_NAME'> </A>
               <A key='REC_STAT'>Locked</A>
            VADB (XXX-XXX-XXXX): 000-000-0000 
            CHANNEL MULTICAST ADDRESS: 224.0.1.8 
            LAN2 SUBNET MASK: 255.255.255.192 
            8 PORT HUB: No 
            </A>
               <A key='GO_NOTE'>This is a Quality)</A>
               <A key='RAMA'>2573</A>
              </DSO_INFO>
             <LAMBDA_INFO>
              <PARAM>
               <A key='PARAMDESC'>IP ADDRESS</A>
               <A key='PARAMVAL'>10.6.6.6</A>
              </PARAM>
              <PARAM>
               <A key='PARAMDESC'>POP (XXX-XXX-XXXX)</A>
               <A key='PARAMVAL'>000-000-0000</A>
              </PARAM>
              <PARAM>
               <A key='PARAMDESC'>ADDRESS</A>
               <A key='PARAMVAL'>3.4.5.6</A>
              </PARAM>
             </LAMBDA_INFO>
             <MOA_INFO>
              <MOA>
               <A key='MOA_ID'>11111</A>
               <A key='ENT_DT'>01/15/2012 02:33:22</A>
              </MOA>
              <MOA>
               <A key='MOA_ID'>11111</A>
               <A key='ENT_DT'>01/15/2012 02:33:22</A>
               <A key='ENT_BY'>Creation</A>
              </MOA>
             </MOA_INFO>
             <DETACH_INFO>
             </DETACH_INFO>
            </PO>
            </ALPHA_Output>
```

Comment: What would you like to compare? I would probably parse the info I'd like to compare and add it to a dictionary. Then I would try to create a matching dict...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unlike other web forums you may have used before, SO is a question-and-answer site. It isn't a problem-and-solution site and it isn't a coding service. Members, such as yourself, ask questions and other members attempt to answer them. I notice that your post is missing the essential element: there is no question.  What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: For example I created 2 dictionaries but got error as dict1 contains extra  key:value pair(Beta:deep)


    dict1 = {'Name': 'rohan', 'Age': 7,'Alpha':'test','Beta':'deep'};
    dict2 = {'Name': 'Mahnaz', 'Age': 27,'Alpha':'test'};
    dicdiff = [k for k in dict1 if dict1[k] != dict2[k]]
    for k in dicdiff:
    print k, ':', dict1[k], '->', dict2[k]